# Python psycopg2 error vars function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a piece of code that work fine on a server and don't work on other server ( Linux servers)

```
import psycopg2,psycopg2.extras
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=xx.x.x.x dbname=dev user=user password=pass" )
parentId='272'
dbCur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
dbCur.execute('select * from "treeItem" where "parentId" = %s order by "order"',(parentId,))
for row in dbCur:
    print type(row)
    print row.__dict__
    vars(row)
dbCur.close()
conn.close()
```

The output on the server error is :

```
class 'psycopg2.extras.Record'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    print row.__dict__
AttributeError: 'Record' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

but it work on the other server without problem.
Same version of python (2.7) and psycopg2 2.5

How class psycopg2.extras.Record can have `__dict__` on an environment and not in other? 
**Edit**
Work on python 2.7.3 and psycopg2 2.5 (dt dec pq3 ext) 
Dont work on python 2.7.5 psycopg2 2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)

Comment: How certain are you that you have the same version of psycopg2 in both environments? If the `Record` object has a `__slots__` attribute in later versions then instances won't have a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: In fact, `NamedTupleCursor` is your hint here: `namedtuple` objects use `__slots__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Then shouldn't this fail? `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])(1, 2).__dict__`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: `__dict__` returns an OrderedDict in recent versions of Python 2.7; let me see where that was added.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: 2.7.3

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Good sleuthing.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: yeah, the fact that it was *removed* for 2.7.5 is especially interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor`, which produces instances of a class produced with the [`collections.namedtuple()` class factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). These classes use `__slots__` to limit their memory use.

Normally, classes with `__slots__` don't have a `__dict__` attribute. However, in Python 2.7.3 a `__dict__` property was added (see [revision 26d5f022eb1a](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/26d5f022eb1a/)), specifically to support `vars()` use. A [later change](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/18303391b981/) removed the support again from Python 2.7.5, then it was [readded for Python 2.7.6](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/687295c6c8f2/). The property acts as a proxy, calling  `namedtuple._asdict()` to produce an `OrderedDict` object.

You have a Python 2.7.x release that doesn't have the property; e.g. one of 2.7, 2.7.1, 2.7.2 or 2.7.5. You can work around this by calling the [`namedtuple._asdict()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) instead:

```
for row in dbCur:
    print type(row)
    print row._asdict()
```

Comment: Another possible workaround would be to use a [`psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor).  A side effect of this would be that rows could no longer be indexed using integer indices.